# Animate placeholder for an input field event when user inputs something there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen demos like [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/qNmjw/1/)

But it's about creating a new element.

```
parent().append("<span>" + $input.attr('placeholder') + "</span>");
```

Is there a way to animate placeholder's disappear on `input event` without appending a new element?

```js
$("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
    
    var $input = $(this);
    // wrap the input with a label
    $input.wrap("<label class='placeholder'>");
    // append a span to the label
    $input.parent().append("<span>" + $input.attr('placeholder') + "</span>");
    // and finally remove the placeholder attribute
    $input.attr('placeholder', '');
    
}).keyup(function () {
    
    var $input = $(this);
    // toogle hidden class on span, according to whether there is content or not
    if ($input.val() === "") {
        $input.next("span").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $input.next("span").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

```css
label.placeholder {
    position: relative;
}

label.placeholder span {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 250ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 250ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity 250ms;
    transition: opacity 250ms;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: grey;
}

label.placeholder span.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="the placeholder">
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/manifestinteractive/pen/viaAK?  (not mine)

Comment: @Firedrake969 it disappears on click, not on text input. by "input" in the Questio header I meant the JS/JQ event, "input".

Comment: @knitevision i think you mean on keypress not "input"

Comment: since you can't manipulate css pseudo elements via javascript you might have to do manually insert and remove styles on events http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/

Comment: you can use pseudo elements instead of span, but you still need a wrap element (input do not have pseudo). See http://jsfiddle.net/qNmjw/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to animate placeholder's disappear on input event without appending a new element?

Since the default browser pseudo elements (i.e., `::-webkit-input-placeholder`/`::-moz-placeholder`, `:-ms-input-placeholder`) are difficult to style across browsers, you could use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element in place of the appended `span` element. However, since pseudo elements can't be added to `input` elements, you would still need to wrap the `input` element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c43ugdgo/)

The pseudo element is positioned absolutely *relative* to the parent so that it covers the parent element. The `content` value of the pseudo element is based on the wrapper element's custom `data-*` attribute, `data-placeholder`, this is achieved using the `content` value `attr(data-placeholder)`.

I also simplified your jQuery a little:

```js
$('input[placeholder]').each(function () {
    $(this).wrap('<label class="placeholder" data-placeholder="' + this.placeholder + '">').attr('placeholder', '');
}).on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hidden', this.value !== '');
});
```

```css
label.placeholder {
    position: relative;
}
label.placeholder:after {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    position: absolute;
    top:0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: grey;
    cursor: text;
    transition: opacity 250ms;
}
label.hidden.placeholder:after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="the placeholder"/>
```

---

In case of long `placeholder` values, you could also add the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vxprLvp/)

```
label.placeholder:after {
    /* .. */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```